# Delete columns based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete columns based on multiple criteria.

My sheet has 800 columns.

1. I would like to delete columns based on Row 2 values.

   - If the value in row 2 is blank, delete entire column.
   - If the value is greater than 1000 and less than 250 delete.
2. I also have values in row 3 that I can check against

   - If the cell contains the word ARR or SFR, keep
   - Otherwise, delete the entire column.

---

```
Sub deleteColumns ()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim i As Long
    i = 800
    For c = i To 1 Step -1 
        If trim(Cells(2,c).Value) = “” Then
            Columns(c).Delete
            ' What should the code be for testing the portion if cell value is  
            ' greater than 250 and less than 1000, delete? 
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry - not trying to be lazy. Just don't know enough to write an example.

Comment: There are countless examples of how to do this online. I don't follow how 1 and 2 are related. Does one trump the other?

Comment: Thanks, SJR. I am still trying to find an example for works. 1) and 2) are not related, but I can use either 1) or 2) to achieve what I need since the Excel sheet has the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reckon you could have figured this out yourself. If it's not quite what you need I also reckon you could amend it as you need.

```
Sub deleteColumns()

Dim c As Long
Dim i As Long

i = 800

For c = i To 1 Step -1
    If Trim(Cells(2, c).Value) = vbNullString Or Cells(2, c).Value < 250 Or Cells(2, c).Value > 1000 Then
        Columns(c).Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you SJR. I have been searching for hours since I am such a newbie with VBA. This works (w minor tweaks) for my purpose. THANK YOU!

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is to watch out for text values.

Comment: Thanks - good thing is the report I get is standard, but all the numbers came out as text, so I had to do a conversion before running the macro. Thanks again!